# How do I assert the text in Google Search button with Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I tried to write the auto-test with `Selenium using C#` and `asserts` the text in `Google Search` Button.

However the test got failed.

How to do it correctly and what's wrong here?

```
enter code here
[Test]
    public  void TestIfButtonNameIsGoogleSearch()
    {
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl");

        var btnSearch = Driver.FindElements(By.Name("btnK"));
        if(btnSearch.Count==2)
        {
            Assert.That(true);
        }

        string expName = btnSearch.LastOrDefault().Text;
        Assert.AreEqual(expName, "Google Search");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.GetAttribute("value")` instead of `.Text`

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code. By default inputs are holding the text in 'value' attribute. Normaly its hidden.
Code Example:

```
var btnSearch = Driver.FindElements(By.Name("btnK"));
var btnFeelingLucky = Driver.FindElements(By.Name("btnI"));

var searchBtnText = btnSearch.GetAttribute("value");
var feelingLuckyBtnText = btnFeelingLucky.GetAttribute("value");

Assert.AreEqual(searchBtnText , "Google Search");
Assert.AreEqual(feelingLuckyBtnText , "I'm Feeling Lucky");
```

If the 'value' does not return anything or its empty, you can try with:

```
string btnText = javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].value", searchBtnText) as string;
```